# Binding textbox to Decimal "fallback value" on input error

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I was testing the nuances of Data Binding in WPF today, and I came across a strange problem.

In my View, I have

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding MyInt, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, StringFormat='{}{##.##}'}"/>        
<Label Content="{Binding MyStr2}"/>
```

In my ViewModel, I have

```
    private decimal myInt;

    public decimal MyInt
    {
        get { return myInt; }
        set
        {
            if (value == myInt) { return; }
            myInt = value;               
            OnPropertyChange();
            OnPropertyChange("MyStr2");
        }
    }

    public string MyStr2
    {
        get
        {
            return myInt.ToString("N2", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-IN"));
        }

    }
```

I want to get the data from the textbox, and format it properly and display it in a label. Simple and easy.

Now, I can only enter decimal data in the textbox, or else the border turns red, indicating an input error.

All is fine when I input decimal data:[image: Working fine]

But, when I enter garbage data, this happens:[image: Error]

The red border shows there is data input error. But, the label still reflects the older data. I want the label to fall back to 0.00 in case of input error. Is there any way to do that?

I have tried to find a contrived way to do it, and it works, sort of, in an extremely hacky kludgy way.

```
    private string myInt;
    private decimal myIntActual;

    public string MyInt
    {
        get
        {
            return myInt;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == myInt) { return; }
            Decimal.TryParse(value.ToString(), out myIntActual);
            myInt = myIntActual.ToString();
            Decimal.TryParse(myInt, out myIntActual);
            OnPropertyChange();
            OnPropertyChange("MyStr2");
        }
    }

    public string MyStr2
    {
        get
        {
            return myIntActual.ToString("N2", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-IN"));
        }
    }
```

What this does is that, it takes the input as a string, tries to parse it to decimal, if it cant, it will return zero. But I have sacrificed the input validation with this code, not to mention that the code looks ugly.

I understand that WPF has a fallback value mechanism when binding fails. Is there any fallback value mechanism in case of input error?

EDIT:

One more thing. After entering the garbage data, the next time I enter valid data, the value somehow reaches the viewmodel, but the textbox becomes blank. And it is a reproducible problem.

Screenshot A:

[image: Working correctly]

This is working as is expected.

[image: Garbage data]

The garbage data is then entered. Do note that, as the `UpdateSourceTrigger` is `LostFocus`, the error does not come up until the focus is lost.

[image: Valid data]

I then enter valid data, and...

[image: Gone!]

on losing focus, the textbox blanks out. Do note, that the label is properly updated. I set up breakpoints to see if the binded property is updated or not, and it is, yet the textbox becomes blank. Why is that?

Comment: The behavior in the first case is due to the fact that it hasn't accepted the input at all. I think from a usability standpoint, the formatted string representing the value is the last valid value the user entered. To me, that makes sense just as it is. But you could write a trigger on Validation.HasError which would hide the MyStr2 label when the MyInt text box is in an error state.

Comment: How should I do it in MVVM? I mean, as it is the view's concern, should I put the code in the codebehind?

Comment: There's no C# there. It's all XAML. I'll shoot you an example in a bit.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. That's even better.

Comment: And please do check the addendum to my question. That's a strange behavior, which might be a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the trigger idea. I tested this and it's working for me. It works with no changes to your viewmodel or code behind.

```
<TextBox 
    x:Name="MyIntTextBox"
    Text="{Binding MyInt, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, StringFormat='{}{##.##}'}"
    />
<Label Content="{Binding MyStr2}">
    <Label.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Label" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Label}}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <!-- 
                parens on (Validation.HasError) are important: It's an attached 
                so its name has a dot in it. The parens tell the binding that.
                --> 
                <DataTrigger 
                    Binding="{Binding (Validation.HasError), ElementName=MyIntTextBox}" 
                    Value="True">
                    <Setter 
                        Property="Visibility" 
                        Value="Hidden" 
                        />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Label.Style>
</Label>
```

As for the blank-out behavior, I see that when I type an invalid string into the MyInt box, tab out, tab back in, type a valid value, and tab back out. It only happens when I tab out on a valid value, when the previous value that I tabbed out on was invalid. I think that's exactly the (mis)behavior you're describing.

I don't have an explanation for that. I don't like to run around yelling "bug" on a framework, but I think that's a bug. The control isn't showing the viewmodel property value it's bound to, and the value hasn't changed. I put a breakpoint in the MyInt setter and it only hits the breakpoint once, with the new valid value (aside from the fact that as far as I know there's no integer value that's displayed as an empty string).

I would ask about that as a separate question if google doesn't turn up any workarounds. I tried "wpf textbox invalid tab out empty" and got nothing.

Comment: Thank you. That worked for me perfectly. As for the alleged bug, I will post a separate question. I went through most of the Google search results, but no one seems to have reported it.